# How can I remove oil/ATF from a newly paved driveway?

Tags: cleaning, driveway

I had my asphalt driveway repaved this spring, and of course my car has started leaking - ATF in this case.

How can I remove it?

Comment: What kind of driveway?  Concrete, asphalt, ...?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2853/74694.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First fix the leak! Then attack the stain with a bristle brush and some dish detergent; if that doesn't do it, there are commercial cleaners for asphalt or concrete, like this that are a bit stronger. Don't expect 100% results, but the stain will fade over time:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A cheaper and quick way is to spray or pour a standard house cleaner such as Windex or laundry detergent on the spot you need cleaned and leave it for a good 15 to 20 minutes then rinse with warm water and it should go away especially if it is fresh leak. Good luck!

Comment: Windex and laundry detergent have very different properties. Any info on whether either of these will clean ATF or negatively interact with asphalt or concrete?