# Removing stains from concrete

Tags: cleaning, concrete

How can I remove stains from concrete (garage/driveway)?  The stains are most likely either oil, gasoline, or transmission fluid.

Comment: See http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-and-prevent-leaf-stains-on-concrete-pavers (not the same staining agent, but...)

Comment: And this:  http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/oil-stain-on-driveway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of concrete cleaning products on the market, but I have had good luck with a 1 gallon solution of 1/4 bleach, 1 cup TSP and 3/4 water. Assuming you are talking about a driveway or garage floor, I would pressure wash the area first to get off the surface crud, then lay on some of the solution and let it set 5 mins or so.  Scrub it down with a stiff broom and power wash again.  Repeat this as necessary.
As a last resort, you can also use some muriatic acid, but test a small area first to be sure it doesn't effect the color too much.

Comment: TSP is a non-sudsing powdered Trisodium Phosphate compound that is formulated for heavy duty cleaning. (For anyone who had to look it up as well.)

Answer (score 1):

If they are stains that just happened, i usually use sawdust or kitty litter.  These soak it up nicely.  If they have been there for a while, it may be too late.